# take two columns from txt file in python and do bucketing

Tags: python

I have a text file which each column is separated by comma and I want to take only the last columns, and to print the two lines for each unique case and tell how many times it appends in the file.

**for example:**
txt file:

apple,banana,mellon

apple,banana,mellon

kiwi,banana,mellon

kiwi,mango,banana

apple,mango,banana

**the output should be:**

banana mellon 3

mango banana 2

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried implementing something rudimentary, but I'm not sure if this meets your use case nor if it's the most optimal way to do so.

```
def bucketing(filename = 'input.txt'):
    content = [x.strip().split(',')[1:] for x in open(filename, 'r').readlines() if x.strip() != '']
    unique = {'{0} {1}'.format(x[0], x[1]):0 for x in content}

    for item in content:
        unique['{0} {1}'.format(item[0], item[1])] += 1

    output = ''
    for key in unique:
        output += key + ' ' + str(unique[key]) + '\n\n'
    return output.strip()
```

Comment: It it more or less what I did, I thought there was an easier way to do it
thank you!